# Insights through Graph/FQ: as in dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to import FB insights as displayed on the insights dashboard Traffic > Stream Publish.
Stories Published, is available (application_stream_stories i guess)
Story Impressions, this i cannot seem to find in de docs.
Story Clicks, i also cannot seem to find this.

Does anyone have an idea where to look / what to try?

Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

You can find them after a succesfull deploy ultimately tomorrow